# Find all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ satisfying $\det(I+A^n)=(1+\det(A))^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Problem:** Find all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ satisfying
>   $$\det(I+A^n)=(1+\det(A))^n.$$

Clearly, the identity matrix $I$ works because
$$\det(I+I^n)=\det(2I)=2^n=(1+\det(I))^n.$$
Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The square zero matrix works as well.

Comment: How about a nilpotent matrix $A$?

Comment: Any diagonal matrix $A = cI,\; c  \in \mathbb R$ works.

Comment: To generalize both of the previous comments, $A$ could be any matrix whose eigenvalues are all equal — if $k$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$, then both sides are equal to $(1+k^n)^n$. If $n=2$, it's not hard to show that these are the only possible $A$; for larger $n$, they seem not to be...

Comment: @Micah One eigenvalue of multiplicity $n$ is too restrictive. For example, for odd $n$ one can have eigenvalues as the $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity.

Answer (score 5):

We just need that:
$$\prod_{\sigma\in\text{Spec}(A)}(1+\sigma^n)=\left(1+\prod_{\sigma\in\text{Spec}(A)}\sigma\right)^n \tag{1}$$
that can be achieved in many ways. However, if $\text{Spec}(A)\subset[0,+\infty)$ (that happens if $A$ is positive semi-definite, for instance), by the super-additivity of the geometric mean (LHS$>$RHS) it follows that $(1)$  may hold only if $\text{Spec}(A)=\{\sigma\}$.